# Web service call in Microsoft Exchange Server

Tags: exchange-server

I got a new task to identify any features exist in the Microsoft Exchange server such that when a new mail has come to abc@abc.com email id then Exchange server should trigger a web service.

## Exchange Web Services (EWS) in Exchange 2010

https://www.outlook.com

## EWS Managed API:

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
{

   bool result = false;

   Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

   if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
   {
      result = true;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra .....Question is: Does Microsoft Exchange server has ability to call a webservice when a new mail dropped in a user Exchange mailbox?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at EWS Notifications https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx .

If this is Outlook.com or Office 365 then look at WebHooks in the new REST api https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/notify-rest-operations